# How to separate json parsed data when several encodes are being used?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I currently have one query that I send the result via json. I am wanting to build several other queries in this same file and also send them to the file via json.

My question is: How would I separate the json parsed data when several encodes are being used?

For instance, if I had several more of these:

```
echo json_encode($rowCountA);

echo json_encode($rowCountB);

echo json_encode($rowCountC);
```

How could I add onto what I have here and break out the data.

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
$('#totalCatalogViews').html(obj);
```

To something like

```
objA = JSON.parse(data);
objB = JSON.parse(data);
objC = JSON.parse(data);

$('#A').html(objA);
$('#B').html(objB);
$('#C').html(objC);
```

JS

```
function ajaxCallCatalogs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/catalogSelect.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#totalCatalogViews').html(obj);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP

```
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_catalog_total = "
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM catalog_download_now
    ";
    $total_result = $con->prepare($sql_catalog_total);
    $total_result->execute();
    $rowCount = $total_result->fetchColumn();
}   
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    echo json_encode($rowCount);
```

UPDATE:

```
echo json_encode(['totalCount' => $rowCountTotal, 'totalProfile' => $rowCountProfile, 'totalProfilePopular' => $rowCountProfilePopular ]);


$.ajax({
        url: 'php/catalogSelect.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#totalCatalogViews').html(data.totalCount);
            $('#totalProfileViews').html(data.totalProfile);
        }
    });

<div id="totalCatalogViews"></div>
<div id="totalProfileViews"></div>
```

Comment: Put them into a big array container and encode that?

Comment: So something like:  `echo json_encode[$rowCountA, $rowCountB, $rowCountC];`? How would I parse/separate the array to make them into different variables then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For easy recognition

```
json_encode(['rowa' => $rowCountA, 'rowb' => $rowCountB, 'rowc' => $rowCountC ]);
```

Then to look at the data

```
function ajaxCallCatalogs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/catalogSelect.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            // as you used datatype: 'json', you dont need to JSON.parse()
            // it will be dont by jQuery automatically
            //obj = JSON.parse(data);


            // I dont know what you r HTML looks like but for example
            $('#totalCatalogViews').html(data.rowa + data.rowb + data.rowc);

            // or individually
            $('#RowAViews').html(data.rowa);

        }
    });
}
```

But a simple look with the javascript debugger (F12) in the browser will show you what is returned and what `data` looks like

Comment: Would this be `obj = JSON.parse(data);`  then ... `obj = JSON.parse('rowa');` .... `obj = JSON.parse('rowb');` etc ?

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I am getting the values showing up in the response tab, but not actually in the html. I am updating my question to show you how I have this.

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't be populating to the html?

Comment: After putting back in `obj = JSON.parse(data);` and then calling like `.html(obj.totalCount);` it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this.  First, if you are forming an overall structure for your response, it's best to send one JSON object so that you can identify each structure with it's own key.  This is what @RiggsFolly is suggesting, and is the normal approach.

There is an alternative though, and that is to use [Newline-Delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/).  This is common in cases where you will be returning many records, and you want to stream the output.

For example, suppose I select 100,000 records from my database and I want to send them as JSON to the client.  It's not a great idea to JSON-encode that whole array of records because it will take a lot of memory and will generally require parsing the whole result set before returning the first result.

However, if you encode each record separately and separate the JSON-encoded data by newline characters, it's possible for the client to easily parse each record separately and handle the data in a streaming way, saving memory and making the whole operation more efficient.